# For how long viruses survive in non-air moisture environments?

Tags: virology, coronavirus, hiv, safety

On the Internet there are plenty of information that viruses don't live long after they were exposed to air, after they starting to dry out.
But it's hard to find an information on how long viruses can survive in wet non-alive environments at a room temperature like food, oils, soap.
I understand that it varies from virus to virus, but there may be maximal (for the most survivable ones) or average values.

Comment: Depends on the virus. They have PH, and temperature requirements that can't be disrupted. If completely disrupted then the virus denatures causing it to no longer have the effect it had.

Comment: @Ark Lomas thanks for info. I know it depends on the virus, but there must be maximal (for the most survivable ones) or average values.